# If a transformation from R to R satisfies A(cx)=cAx for all c and x in R, can we apply linearity to x (the variable)?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

[image]

According to the solution, we have Ax=A(1x)=xA(1)=ax. I am curious as to why we can pull out the x like that. I thought linearity only applied to the fixed scalar c and not the variable?

Comment: The reason why we can do that here is that we are in $\mathbb{R}$, so the set of "scalars" and the set of "vectors" coincide, so the vector $c \cdot x$ is the same vector as $x\cdot c$ because of commutativity of multiplication in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @William does my answer answer your question ?

Answer (score 0):

If $A(cx)=cA(x)$ for all $x,c\in \mathbb{R}$ then $A(1\times m)=mA(1)$ for all $m\in \mathbb{R}$ because if there exists a $m$ such that $A(1\times m)$ is not equal to $mA(1)$ then there exists a $c$ (equal to $m$) and $x$ (equal to $1$) such that the first equation is not satisfied , hence for every $m\in \mathbb{R}$ it’s true.So for every $x$ belonging to $\mathbb{R}$ it’s true .